# Error in pom.xml while running Storm API project in windows XP

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am trying to run a Storm API project in my windows XP desktop,but the project is showing build failure with following message in the console..

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...r\r\n   | the parameter in question.\r\n   |\r\n   | Default: true\r\n  <i... @61:5)  @ C:\Documents and Settings\377445\.m2\settings.xml, line 61, column 5
[WARNING] 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.rapportive.storm:storm-amqp-spout:jar:0.2.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 134, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.141s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 13 12:33:12 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

The project in eclipse (Indigo) is showing following errors in pom.xml file..

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Missing artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1
    - Missing artifact org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2
    - Missing artifact ring:ring-jetty-adapter:jar:0.3.11
    - Missing artifact javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1
    - Missing artifact commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1
    - Missing artifact org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211
    - Missing artifact storm:storm:jar:0.8.1
    - Missing artifact com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1
    - Missing artifact hiccup:hiccup:jar:0.3.6
    - Missing artifact commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4
    - Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4
    - Missing artifact com.netflix.curator:curator-client:jar:1.0.1
    - Missing artifact com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0
    - ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to 
     transfer log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.16 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
     reattempted until the update interval of Apache has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:
     1.2.16 from/to Apache (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): NullPointerException
    - Missing artifact org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:3.5.1
    - Missing artifact jline:jline:jar:0.9.94
    - Missing artifact javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4
    - Missing artifact org.drools:drools-core:jar:5.5.0.Final
    - Missing artifact com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2
    - Missing artifact ring:ring-core:jar:0.3.10
    - Missing artifact com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.1
    - Missing artifact org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0
    - Missing artifact antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7
    - Missing artifact compojure:compojure:jar:0.6.4
    - Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
    - Missing artifact org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.9
    - Missing artifact org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26
    - Missing artifact org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1
    - Missing artifact org.clojure:tools.macro:jar:0.1.0
    - Missing artifact org.drools:knowledge-api:jar:5.5.0.Final
    - Missing artifact org.clojure:tools.logging:jar:0.2.3
    - Missing artifact org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.1.3.Final
    - Missing artifact ring:ring-servlet:jar:0.3.11
    - Missing artifact org.drools:knowledge-internal-api:jar:5.5.0.Final
    - Missing artifact org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3
    - Missing artifact org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.3
    - Missing artifact org.clojure:core.incubator:jar:0.1.0
    - Missing artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1
    - Missing artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.0-801.jdbc4
    - Missing artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15
    - Missing artifact storm:jgrapht:jar:0.8.3
    - Missing artifact storm:carbonite:jar:1.5.0
    - Missing artifact commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4
    - Missing artifact com.netflix.curator:curator-framework:jar:1.0.1
    - Missing artifact com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.0.2
    - Missing artifact org.clojure:math.numeric-tower:jar:0.0.1
    - Missing artifact com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07
    - Missing artifact org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.3.3
    - ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5: ArtifactResolutionException: 
     Failure to transfer javax.servlet:servlet-api:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution 
     will not be reattempted until the update interval of Apache has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
     javax.servlet:servlet-api:pom:2.5 from/to Apache (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): NullPointerException
    - Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1
    - Missing artifact org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26
    - Missing artifact storm:tools.cli:jar:0.2.2
    - Missing artifact clout:clout:jar:0.4.1
    - Missing artifact org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:5.5.0.Final
    - Missing artifact xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1
    - Missing artifact org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.4.0
    - Missing artifact backtype:jzmq:jar:2.1.0
    - Missing artifact com.googlecode.disruptor:disruptor:jar:2.10.1
```

I have installed Storm-0.8.1 but I am not sure whether it is properly installed in windows XP.Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]

You have to specify a particular goal when issuing the maven command. Something from the list of possible goals as given in the the error above. The 2 (most basic commands) required are `mvn clean` and `mvn install`

1. `mvn clean` -> It will attempt to clean the build direcotory of the projectt. If you go into the detail documentation, it invloves deleting the files and folders inside `$project_dir$/target` directory.
2. `mvn install` -> This will make the build. The install build cycle follows multiple goals/phases which include compiling,testing,copying required resources, packaging and then finally installing the artifact inside your local m2 repo. Some people favor the use of `mvn package` over `mvn install` if you dont want the artifact to be installed inside your local repo ( like e.g its pointless to install war files there)

For more detail documentation I suggest you look into the [5min maven guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to 
>        transfer log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.16 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
>        reattempted until the update interval of Apache has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:
>        1.2.16 from/to Apache (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): NullPointerException

Make sure that you are connected to the internet and that all fire-walls and proxies are properly configure to allow access to mvn central